# How to get missing lines from a file?

Tags: import, string-manipulation

Let's say I have this file dat.csv which basically is a number of strings like that:

```
animal horse duck dog
plant tree grass sunflower
sky oxygen nytrogen air
```

Then in dat2.csv I have

```
animal horse  dog
plant  grass sunflower
sky oxygen nytrogen
```

I would like a third file to be saved with the first columm and the missing word

```
   animal duck 
   plant tree
   sky air
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Can you show what you tried and where you got stuck?  These are not CSV files because the values are not comma separated. `Import` using the `"Table"` format (not `"CSV"`). Then look up `Complement`.

Comment: I mean, I got csv with the strings separataed by comma, but I could easy substitute them with a space on notepad. I will try what you said, give me a few

Comment: So you have already solved the problem of reading the data in?  This is a good example of why you should always be very precise in your question.  I think this question is too broad.  Where do you get stuck?  Reading the data? Extracting the first column?  Extracting the missing word, given two lists of strings?  Please break it down.

Comment: hmm makes sense. I will see where exactly is my error then I edit the question

Comment: `Flatten /@ ({First @@ #, Complement @@ #} & /@ 
   GatherBy[Join[dat, dat2], First])` gives {{"animal", "duck"}, {"plant", "tree"}, {"sky", "air"}}  from the following data:  dat = {{"animal", "horse", "duck", "dog"}, {"plant", "tree", "grass", 
   "sunflower"}, {"sky", "oxygen", "nytrogen", "air"}}, dat2 = {{"plant", "grass", "sunflower"}, {"sky", "oxygen", 
   "nytrogen"}, {"animal", "horse", "dog"}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested import the data using "*Table*".

```
dat = Import["dat.csv", "Table"]
(* {{"animal", "horse", "duck", "dog"}, {"plant", "tree", 
  "grass", "sunflower"}, {"sky", "oxygen", "nytrogen", "air"}} *)

dat2 = Import["dat2.csv", "Table"]
(* {{"animal", "horse", "dog"}, {"plant", "grass", 
  "sunflower"}, {"sky", "oxygen", "nytrogen"}} *)
```

Now `Map` the function `Complement` to the lines found in `dat`

```
Map[
 Flatten[{dat[[#, 1]], Complement[dat[[#]], dat2[[#]]]}] &, 
 Range@Length@dat]
(* {{"animal", "duck"}, {"plant", "tree"}, {"sky", "air"}} *)
```

Note that this code will only work if there is a one to one correspondence between the lines in `dat.csv` and `dat2.csv`.

Something more sophisticated will be required if you also need to match the lines.

### Match Lines

The case where one needs to match lines is treated essentially identically to where there is a one to one correspondence but it is necessary to set up a cross reference between the two sets of row numbers.

Assume that the first CSV file is:

```
dat = Import["dat.csv", "Table"]
(* {{"animal", "horse", "duck", "dog"}, 
{"planet", "mercury", "jupiter"},
 {"plant", "tree", "grass", "sunflower"},
 {"sky", "oxygen", "nytrogen", "air"}} *)
```

and the second CSV file is

```
dat2 = Import["dat2.csv", "Table"]
(* {{"plant", "grass", "sunflower"},
 {"animal", "horse", "dog"},
 {"sky", "oxygen", "nytrogen"}} *)
```

The first step is to set up a cross reference which indicates the row number where the first element in each row of `dat` can be found in `dat2`. Note that one has to cover the case where the row in `dat` is missing from `dat2`. I suspect there is a simpler way of doing this but a first pass brute force approach is:

```
crossReference = Map[
  With[
    {position = Position[dat2, dat[[#, 1]]]},
    If[SameQ[Dimensions[position], {1, 2}],
     {#, position[[1, 1]]},
     Nothing
     ]
    ] &,
  Range@Length@dat]
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 3}} *)
```

With the `crossReference` computed we perform the same operation as in the first case but use the indices from `crossReference`.

```
Map[
 Flatten[{dat[[#[[1]], 1]], 
    Complement[dat[[#[[1]]]], dat2[[#[[2]]]]]}] &, crossReference]
(* {{"animal", "duck"}, {"plant", "tree"}, {"sky", "air"}} *)
```

Comment: that kind works. I just forgot to mention that my lines are mixed up. Not necessarily at the same order. How could I fix that?

Comment: Can you clarify 'not necessarily at the same order' ? Is it that {"animal", "horse", "dog"} does not necessarily appear on row 1 in dat2 but the first position in each set correctly gives the general class of element (? use GatherBy), or that dat2 may contain something like { "horse", "animal", "dog", '} ?